# Why is non-zeroed memory only a problem with big data usage?

Tags: memory-management, heap-memory

I was doing a graded programming assignment — an implementation of Rope data structure. The grader fed it an initial string and a series of edit operations. I did my development in C++ on a Linux machine. After testing my solution locally with small inputs (a string of ca 10 chars) I posted it to the grader, but got Segmentation Fault on one of the test cases.

I have generated a random input data with the maximum size given in the assignment specs (the string of 300k characters). I also got the Segmentation Fault locally. After a short debugging I found out that the leaves of my tree had random `left` and `right` pointers instead of `NULL`. After replacing the `new Vertex` calls with `new Vertex()` (the latter calls the default constructor, unlike the former which leaves the memory as-is) the code worked fine and got accepted by the grader.

This however makes me wonder — why did my code work correctly with a small input, both locally and on the grader’s machine? Is some amount of heap guaranteed to be zeroed when I run a process? Is this an artifact of some previously run program? What exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

Uninitialised objects can have any value. Uninitialised pointers can contain null, they can contain valid pointers by coincidence, or contain invalid pointers. It is completely undefined. Your program will behave accordingly. And it’s quite possible that memory is filled with some amount of zeroes followed by some amount of rubbish.

There may be a compiler option that will fill uninitialised variables with data that is likely to lead to a crash. More likely, there may be compiler options warning you when you use an uninitialised variable.

Comment: I undestand that it is wrong to assume anything about the content of freshly allocated memory. I know, my initial code was wrong for this reason. However, in this case there seems to be some reason, why, for small amount of allocated data I deteministically get zeros.